# Complexity of iterative deepening search

Tags: graph, tree, depth-first-search, iterative-deepening

I saw a question about "Iterative Deepening Depth-First Search" and I couldn't any answer. If it exists, I am sorry for that.

Question: *How does the complexity of IDS change when the graph is used instead of tree?*

Thank you!

Comment: What graph? what tree?

Comment: Not a specific tree or graph. I guess, it is a general question that compare graph search and tree search. Also, there is no additional information in the question.